# Выдаёт ошибку "Unable to open file .. OBJ"

Tags: c++, radstudio

Делаю программу, раньше компилировалась нормально, но вот сейчас выводит ошибку:

> [ILINK32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'UTF8CONTENTPARSER.OBJ'

Как исправить? В коде ну ничего вроде не менял) 
Пишу в rad studio XE

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит выполнить очистку (clean) проекта и пересобрать его.

Comment: непомогло это